# Moderation Request: Tag Synonym for Soteriology and Salvation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Could moderators please move "Soteriology" as a tag-synonym for "Salvation"?

Or perhaps, could explanations be given (in tag descriptions) showing how these tags are different and how they should be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags should always use the "industry standard" technical terms. In this case [soteriology](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soteriology) would be the best candidate for the tag. Anything else that people frequently tend to come up with should be synonyms of the technical term.

I have gone ahead and merged [salvation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salvation) into [soteriology](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soteriology). For future reference, you or anyone else that wants to suggest synonyms can do so [from this page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), after which they can be voted on and approved by a couple other community members or a moderator. The tag descriptions of course can be edited at any time by almost anybody with a modicum of reputation.

Comment: Caleb - It is not true that anyone can suggest tag-synonyms.  There is a restriction on this - regardless of reputation - or else I would have been doing this a long time ago.

Comment: @elikakohen The tag suggestion priv is [given at 1250 rep](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). By anyone I meant this is not a moderator only thing.

Comment: It does require that much reputation.  But it ALSO requires 5 reputation in that tag, (which isn't possible if it is a new tag).  Or perhaps it is 5 reputation in moderating that tag??  It seems that even I cannot propose synonyms for tags that I have a lot of reputation in.